# Microsoft TFS: Force documentation on checkin

Tags: tfs, documentation, customization, rules

Is there a way to deny checkin of undocumented code-files?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You mean the XML Documentation Comments https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx ?

Comment: What's the detail mean of `ndocumented code-files`?  Did you mean the code should have annotation ?

Comment: Giulio: Yes, thats what i am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a gated check-in build. In the build use a task (you will need to write your own task) which will identify if any undocumented code-files are present. This adds an overhead to the dev team though, that they got to wait for the build to complete and you will need a powerful build system for quicker builds.

Or you can define a custom checkin policy to deny checking in certain files. However you will need to get the logic of finding undocumented code-file. In order not to override the policy you need a server side plug in, which is documented here http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2014/05/13/turning-off-policy-overrides-in-tfs/